# airflow-scheduler not accept mysql settings, start with sqlite. why

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

airflow webserver can run without problem.

airflow scheduler would get error message:
Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting parallelism to 1

airflow.cfg:
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql+pymysql://root:mypassword@localhost:3306/airflow

Answer (score 0):

Have you set $AIRFLOW_HOME wherever you run scheduler too?

Looks like the scheduler is not picking up the `airflow.cfg` file at all.